# nightmare - where does document come from?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nightmare

The code snippet below is an example from https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare

```
const Nightmare = require('nightmare')
const nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true })

nightmare
  .goto('https://duckduckgo.com')
  .type('#search_form_input_homepage', 'github nightmare')
  .click('#search_button_homepage')
  .wait('#r1-0 a.result__a')
  .evaluate(() => document.querySelector('#r1-0 a.result__a').href)
  .end()
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Search failed:', error)
  })
```

I can't wrap my mind around this line:

```
.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('#r1-0 a.result__a').href)
```

Where does the `document` come from? The code is running on Node.js, so no browser context. I've checked that the `document` is not a global variable. Clearly not a parameter too. I've also verified that the example code works. How is it possible?

Comment: In addition to the given answer, on the theoretical aspect, whoever implemented function `evaluate`, could call the function which is passed to it as an argument (the function which uses `document` in your example) inside a `try`/`catch` clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That arrow function is passed as a parameter to be run in the Nightmare headless browser, where `document` is defined.

```
.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('#r1-0 a.result__a').href)
```

You can also pass extra arguments to this function like so:

```
.evaluate((arg) => {
  document.querySelector('#r1-0 a.result__a').href);
}, 'test');
```

Comment: Okay, that explains it. Thanks a lot!